# В каком потоке выполняется subscribe() в RxJava?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rxjava, rxjava2

У меня есть метод **getText()**, который получает из сети текст. Его нужно вставить в TextView.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);

        Observable.fromCallable(() -> getText())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(integer -> textView.setText(integer + ""));
}
```

Загрузку текста я выполняю асинхронно. Как я понимаю должна быть ошибка, что я могу менять интерфейс только в UI потоке. Но ошибки нет. Почему так, если я указываю **Schedulers.io()**?

**UPD**
Исключения не будет даже если укажу observeOn(Schedulers.io()) перед subscribe().

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что проблема вашего кейса в том, что RX Java по каким-то причинам не успевает переключаться с UI потока на рабочий и по этому вы не падаете с ошибкой.  Если же запустить это в дебагере с точкой остановы в `subscribe()` вы получите желаемую ошибку.

Более того если в цепочку добавить delay:

```
Observable.fromArray(1, 2, 3)
                .delay(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(
                        { integer ->
                            view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview_first).text = integer.toString()
                        },
                        { error ->
                            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), error.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        })
```

То вы так же получите ошибку о том, что нельзя обновлять View не на UI потоке.